# Cannot find Region in cache GemFireCache

Tags: gemfile, spring-data-gemfire

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Cannot find region [record] in cache GemFireCache[id = 20255495; 
isClosing = false; isShutDownAll = false;
 closingGatewayHubsByShutdownAll = false; created = Mon Jan 23 11:45:10 EST 2017; server = false; copyOnRead = false; lockLease = 120; lockTimeout = 60]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.RegionLookupFactoryBean.lookupFallback(RegionLookupFactoryBean.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.RegionLookupFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(RegionLookupFactoryBean.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 13 more
```

**My XML File is :**

```xml
<beans>

    ....

    <context:component-scan base-package="spring.gemfire.repository.deptemp"/>

    <gfe:client-cache id="gemfireCache" pool-name="gfPool"/>

    <!--Region for being used by the Record Bean -->
    <gfe:replicated-region id="record" cache-ref="gemfireCache"/>

    <bean id="record" class="spring.gemfire.repository.deptemp.beans.Record"/>

    <gfe:pool id="gfPool" max-connections="10" subscription-enabled="true" >  
        <gfe:locator host="localhost" port="10334"/>        
    </gfe:pool>   

    <gfe:lookup-region id="record" />  
    <gfe-data:repositories base-package="spring.gemfire.repository.deptemp.repos"/>  

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Abhisekh-

Why do you have both this...

```
<gfe:replicated-region id="record" cache-ref="gemfireCache"/>
```

And this...

```
<gfe:lookup-region id="record" />
```

Also, you have defined this...

```
<bean id="record" class="spring.gemfire.repository.deptemp.beans.Record"/>
```

Which (most definitely) overrode your REPLICATE Region bean definition (also with `id="record"`) based on the "order" of your bean definitions in your XML defined above.

While *Spring* first and foremost adheres to dependency order between bean definitions, it will generally follow the declared order when no dependencies (explicit or implicit) exist.

Since `<bean id="record" .../>` comes after `<gfe:replicated-region id="record" ../>`, then `<bean id=`record`../>` overrides the `<gfe:replicated-region id="record"/>` bean definition.

Additionally, the `<gfe:lookup-region>` is not needed since you are not using GemFire/Geode's native configuration (e.g. `cache.xml`) or *Cluster Configuration Service*.

Furthermore, you are declaring a `ClientCache`, so technically probably want a `<gfe:client-region>` to match the GemFire/Geode Server Region, yes?!

While you can create REPLICATE Regions (and even PARTITION Regions) on a client, you typically do not do this since those Regions are NOT part of any distributed system, or cluster of GemFire "Server" nodes.

A client Region (which can be a PROXY, or even a CACHING_PROXY) will distribute data operations to the Server.  Additionally, if you have data that only a particular client needs, then you ought to create local Regions, using `<gfe:local-region>`.

I would definitely read this, first...

http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/basic_config/book_intro.html

Followed by this next...

http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/topologies_and_comm/book_intro.html

Then this...

http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/book_intro.html

And lastly...

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap

-John

Comment: Hey John - Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: updated cache.xml file and now it it not giving the errors.  <gfe:client-cache id="gemfireCache" pool-name="gfPool"/>
<gfe:replicated-region persistent="true" id="record"/>

Comment: I am using CRUDRepository. 
public interface RecordRepository extends CrudRepository<Record, Long>{
 }
 But, the data is not getting saved in the region after I execute the below code
  RecordRepository recRepos = ctx.getBean(RecordRepository.class);
  Record rec1 = new Record(100L,"1","First record");

Comment: In the eclipse console it is showing as if the Record is getting inserted.    100 1 First record     But,the record is not getting inserted in the region.

Comment: query --query="select * from /record"          does not returns any result in the gfsh

Comment: You are still using the wrong Region element in SDG's XML namespace if you want your`ClientCache`application to send data from the client to a Region on the GemFire Server (which also must be named "record").  The correct element is `<gfe:client-region id="record" shortcut="[PROXY|CACHING_PROXY]"/>`, otherwise you are effectively creating local-only Regions and the data won't be sent to the server(s) in the cluster hosting the server-side Region and therefore the data will not be visible from Gfsh, however you attempt to access the data (e.g. OQL or otherwise).